# Convert QDomElement to QDomDocument and vs

Tags: qt, qtxml

I've QDomElement object and did the following to convert it to QDomDocument.

```
// element is the QDomElement object 
QString str;
QTextStream stream(&str, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
element.save(stream, 2); // stored the content of QDomElement to stream

QDomDocument doc;
doc.setContent(str.toUtf8()); // converted the QString to QByteArray
```

But what about the convertion from QDomDocument to QDomElement? By the way, is there any constructive way to convert QDomElement to QDomDocument?

Answer (score 0):

here is the conversion

```
 QDomDocument doc;
 doc.setContent( <YOUR XML GOES HERE> );
 QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
```